# MSSQL deadlock graph only lists one process

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

I have been trying to troubleshoot a deadlock issue, and have captured an XML deadlock graph via SQL Server Profiler (both the Profiler and SQL Server in question are 2014).  I have had to do this sort of thing before, but this one really has me stymied because the XML deadlock info only lists one process... the one that is being chosen as the victim.  Here is the XML, with table/column names scrubbed:

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process47b021c28">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process47b021c28" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="METADATA: database_id = 28 USER_TYPE(user_type_id = 261), lockPartitionId = 0" waittime="1267" ownerId="6009456" transactionname="@equipmentIDs" lasttranstarted="2018-08-06T10:37:58.643" XDES="0x3a53a63b0" lockMode="Sch-S" schedulerid="2" kpid="10512" status="suspended" spid="55" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2018-08-06T10:37:58.607" lastbatchcompleted="2018-08-06T10:37:58.597" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.597" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="(scrubbed)" hostpid="15300" loginname="(scrubbed)" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="5845226" currentdb="28" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671219744" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="68" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x03001c00063d8761a839af0034a9000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="5" stmtstart="436" stmtend="1352" sqlhandle="0x02000000466dca27e95c8209c65527d104fd85037ea1b3520000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
declare @internalGuid uniqueidentifier = N&apos;00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&apos;;
declare @now datetime2 = getdate();

insert into
    MyTable (
        [id],
        [cbr],
        [created],
        [mbr],
        [modified],
        [value1],
        [value2],
        [latitude],
        [longitude],
        [value3],
        [indicator]
    )
select
    [id],
    @internalGuid,
    @now,
    @internalGuid,
    @now,
    [value1],
    [value2],
    [latitude],
    [longitude],
    [value3],
    1
from
    MyOtherTable;    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <metadatalock subresource="USER_TYPE" classid="user_type_id = 261" dbid="28" lockPartition="0" id="lock3a4c33a80" mode="Sch-M">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process47b021c28" mode="Sch-M"/>
     <owner id="process47b021c28" mode="Sch-S" requestType="wait"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process47b021c28" mode="Sch-S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </metadatalock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

user_type_id 261 corresponds to one of my user defined types, and the lock in question appears to be on that type itself, unless I'm misinterpreting this (which is entirely possible).  If that's the case, I assume it's somehow related to only one process showing in the deadlock data.  Note that the query shown in the deadlock data is an insert to a table that has an insert trigger... and that trigger makes use of the user defined type.

EDIT (2018-08-06): Here is a hastily scrubbed version of the trigger code:

```
create trigger [dbo].[TR_MyTable_UpdateDerefTable]
on [dbo].[MyTable]
after insert, update, delete
as
begin
    set nocount on

    declare @myIDs ObjectIDType; -- ObjectIDType is a user-define table type

    insert into @myIDs
        select i.guidItemId
        from inserted i inner join DerefTable ri on i.value1 = ri.guidItemId

        union

        select d.guidItemId
        from deleted d inner join DerefTable ri on d.value = ri.guidItemId;

    declare
        @dataTypeTL int = 1,
        @dataTypeCML int = 2,
        @dataTypeDL int = 5;

    -- Update dereferenced information, if applicable
    if exists(select top 1 1 from @myIDs)
    begin
        update ri set
            [DerefValue] = eq_loc.value2,
            [DerefValueSource] = case
                                    when eq_loc.IsFromSourceTL = 1 then @dataTypeTL
                                    when eq_loc.IsFromSourceCML = 1 then @dataTypeCML
                                    when eq_loc.IsFromSourceDL = 1 then @dataTypeDL
                                    else NULL
                                 end,
            [DerefValueDescription] = lri.itemName,
            [DerefValueType] = lri.itemType,
            [DerefValueCategory] = lri.itemTypeCategory,
            [DerefValueBU] = lri.buId
        from
            @myIDs e
        left join MyTable eq_loc
        on eq_loc.id = (
            select top 1 l.id
            from MyTable as l
            where l.value1 = e.guidItemId
            order by l.[Timestamp] desc 
        )
        left join DerefTable ri on e.guidItemId = ri.DisplayguidId
        left join DerefTable lri on eq_loc.value2 = lri.guidItemId
    end

    set nocount off
end;
```

EDIT (2018-08-06): To make this question clearer, because there is so much context around this that would be difficult for me to post, this is what I would like to have a better understanding of: What are examples of some cases where the deadlock graph XML only lists a single process?  What operations, other than dropping a user-defined type, would assert a lock on a user-defined type?  In my case, given that this is a user defined table type, could the XML information be misleading me to think the type object itself is being locked, when in actuality the *instance* of the table type has a lock? (in that last case I suppose the single process listed would be deadlocking itself)

EDIT (2018-08-07): I have narrowed down the other side of the lock and it is related to the dropping and creating of the user defined type itself.  Signs seem to be pointing to the lock being on the table type definition itself, rather than on data within an instance of the type.  If you recall, this is in the context of a schema upgrade path.  At one point, this user-defined table type (with id of 261, as indicated in the deadlock graph) is dropped and re-created with an additional column and an index.  From there, dozens of other statements (making up many batches) are processed, spanning two subsequent version steps, before hitting the statement that is triggering the deadlock (and that is being chosen as the victim).  The intermediate statements take enough time that I'd be surprised if it was a timing issue, but this is where my understanding starts to fall down.  I don't know what happens with locking of user-defined types in MSSQL, what happens under the hood so to speak.  I can certainly see why the statement in my victim process depends upon the re-definition of that user-defined type... but what I don't yet understand is what additional dependency could arise that results in a deadlock situation.  If I stage my reproduction scenario such that the user-defined type is manually updated beforehand, then comment out drop/create statements for it during the upgrade itself, the entire process functions as expected and completes successfully.

Comment: That is _unexpected_.  Can you post the trigger code, or a simplified repro?  Does this happen consistently?

Comment: I'm also curious about repro code. Specifically, I'm not seeing anything in the above that would require a schema modification (`Sch-M`) lock.

Comment: Thank you both for the interest!  I have updated the original question to include the trigger code.  This is 100% reproducible with specific steps.  The entire context around this is a database schema upgrade and data migration.  If the upgrade is picked up from a particular version (where a version encompassses a set of schema update scripts), this deadlock occurs several versions later in that same process (an upgrade from one version to another "hits" all versions in between).

Comment: I am not an expert as SQL triggers ... that said, you are updating a table (updating MyTable (el) in the "Touch all other records" section) from a trigger on that same table. doesn't that cause an issue - recursion of some sort?

Comment: @DonDickinson although definitely sub-optimal, the recursion is capped to 32 levels according the mssql documentation.  It's something that should be addressed, but doesn't seem it should be contributing to this problem.  The problem is not reproduced outside the context of the aforementioned upgrade/migration, and the scope of that is so large it's taking me a long time to narrow down what exactly is exacerbating it. Given that, I have updated the original question to focus on a few specific points of uncertainty that I have.

Comment: I have been able to narrow down the relevant context from my reproduction scenario, but still am not understanding something fundamental about what's happening with the locking of my user-defined type and how a deadlock situation could occur.  I have added the details to the end of my original question.

Comment: Does the whole drop-and-create type thing happen inside a transaction? Are you inserting rows in the table attached to the trigger as part of this transaction? Is the trigger dropped before this is done? You may be doing things that are simply too tough for the engine's little brain to handle. Changing types mid-stream is an especially hairy operation. If upgrading the type before on its own is an effective workaround, consider structuring things so that you use that. This may involve doing the upgrade in multiple steps, changing some objects multiple times.

Comment: @JeroenMostert that's along the lines of what's been going through my head, but I haven't had enough experience with these aspects to be able to say with any confidence what the root cause is here. To answer your questions, yes this entire process is in one transaction including the insert/trigger. If there's any reference material specific to this situation that you could share (gory details about what happens under the hood when types are created or dropped, and how transactions play into this) I'd really appreciate it - but I've turned up nothing so far. I have a couple ideas to try though.

Comment: @DonDickinson I just verified that the update statement in the trigger, resulting in recursive trigger executions, does not affect this scenario and so I have removed it from the code in the original question.

Comment: I've never seen this particular situation, but it's well documented that transactions cause locks to be held for longer than they would be with single statements (obviously, since the transaction needs to happen atomically). To be clear, what you're seeing here is a bug: a session should never deadlock with itself, because it means the engine is taking out multiple incompatible locks when it should (at best) be upgrading existing ones. At the same time, dropping, creating and then using a type all in one transaction is not a very common scenario, so I can see how the engine could get confused.

Comment: @JeroenMostert This is fascinating, thank you.  For now we are past the issue by simply not using the user defined type in question (in-lining the query that was feeding the type).  If I'm able to reproduce the same issue in a much simpler stand-alone context, do you think it would be helpful in constructing an official answer to this question that could help someone else?  It's just such a weird combination of strange results, not the least of which being that the deadlock graph only includes one process.

Comment: If you can repro this, then not only is an answer here helpful, you should also consider opening an issue with Microsoft Support (if you have a contract) or else on [Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/). Whether MS will get round to fixing it is another matter, but then at least it's documented.

Comment: It seems that what I'm running into is likely the same issue described here: https://sqlperformance.com/2013/11/t-sql-queries/single-tx-deadlock  However, the author of that post does not seem to be getting the goofy deadlock graph that I'm seeing.